# Make link 'clicked' on page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im maintaining a site where I need to 'click' a link with javascript. The href is inline javascript, not a url so I cant just navigate to that url instead.

Im expect this is bad practice (the rest of the site is terrible!) but I need to make the link 'clicked' with javascript. Im using jQuery.

I know this question has been asked before but it seems normally people are trying to follow the link, which I am not.

Comment: You want the link to appear in the color of visited links, did I get this right?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're trying to do, If you aren't trying to follow the link in the anchor what are you trying to do?

Comment: You mean you want to make is "clicked" for CSS / Styling purposes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest possible way I see, is find link by some finder, like by id, and call click on it:

```
$("#my_link_id").click();
```

But better would be to move that inline javascript from link into some function, and leave name of function in href of link, and on page load just call that saved function.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to create a CSS class of "visitedLink" which would have the same CSS as `a:visited`.

However, if you really wanted to actually click the link but not follow it, you could assign an event to the link which returns false (cancelling the default action) and then run `$('#myLink').click();`.

```
$('#myLink').click(function() { return false; });
$('#myLink').click();
//Then unassign/otherwise disable the initial handler.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it seems you would like to style the link after it is clicked.

If this is correct, Try the code below. It will add a class "selected" after the anchor is clicked. Then you can style it how you like.

```
jQuery('.yourAnchor').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('this').addClass('selected');
});
```